# Can you make a child of a child theme?

Tags: wordpress

can you make a child of a child theme? Is there a limit to the depth of theme creation derivation?

For example: Thematic->some child of thematic -> child of the child of thematic

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes, I believe so. Long answer: [Here, in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).